# Как в двумерном динамическом массиве отсортировать четные столбцы по убыванию в С++?

Tags: c++, сортировка

Столкнулся с проблемой, сортировки. Пробовал использовать swap и сортировку пузырьком, ничто не помогает, помогите. Кину пример своего кода, 1 с swap, а 2 с сортировкой пузырьком.
1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int v = 6;
    int l = 0;
    int m = 0;


    int** arr = new int* [v];
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[v];
    }

    //рандомно задаём значения строкам и рядам в матрице
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            arr[i][j] =-3 + rand() % 10;
        }

    }

    //выводим матрицу на экран
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < v+1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < v+1; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                
                l = j;
                m = i;
                cout << "\t" << "l "<< l << "\t";
                cout << "\t" << "m" << m << "\t";
                if ((m + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                    if (arr[m][l] < arr[m - 1][l]) {
                        cout << "!" << arr[m][l] << "\t" << "@" << arr[m - 1][l] << "\t";
                        swap(arr[m][l], arr[m - 1][l]);
                        cout << "!" << arr[m][l] << "\t" << "@" << arr[m - 1][l] << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int v = 6;
    int l = 0;
    int m = 0;


    int** arr = new int* [v];
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[v];
    }

    //рандомно задаём значения строкам и рядам в матрице
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            arr[i][j] =-3 + rand() % 10;
        }

    }

    //выводим матрицу на экран
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < v+1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < v+1; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                
                l = j;
                m = i;
                cout << "\t" << "l "<< l << "\t";
                cout << "\t" << "m" << m << "\t";
                if ((m + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                    if (arr[m][l] < arr[m - 1][l]) {
                        cout << "!" << arr[m][l] << "\t" << "@" << arr[m - 1][l] << "\t";
                        int t = arr[m][l];
                        arr[m][l] = arr[m - 1][l];
                        arr[m - 1][l] = t;
                        cout << "!" << arr[m][l] << "\t" << "@" << arr[m - 1][l] << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Что такое "парные" столбцы? С чем они в паре?

Comment: Парные - те, которые нацело делятся на 2.

Comment: Это четные, а не [парные](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9#:~:text=%D0%9F%D0%90%CC%81%D0%A0%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%991%2C%20%2D%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C%20%2D,(%D0%B2%201%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87.).)...

Comment: полагаю, надо вытаскивать чётную колонку в отдельный массив и там сортировать в STL потом обратно. зы: что-то у вас овердохрена лишнего, имхо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код не компилировал, но должно работать.

```
for (int col = 0; col < v; col += 2)          // Цикл, идущий по четным столбцам
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v - 1; i++)           // Обычная сортировка пузырьком
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < v - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j][col] < arr[j + 1][col])
                swap(arr[j][col], arr[j + 1][col]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, хорошего вечера))